# I am getting error and code stops going to next network device to login.. Networking-Programming Python

Tags: python-3.x, network-programming, netmiko

I have cisoc_ios routers and fortinet firewall and HP switches in "devices_list" but when I run this code and when it hits fortinet firewall , it does not give error as it is not cisco_ios and tries to login.. And after login it gives error as it can not go into config mode(obviously) . So I need to improve my below code so that code throws error when fortinet or hp devices comes instead of trying to login and it shud continue until all devices have been tried.

```
    from getpass import getpass
    from netmiko import ConnectHandler
    from netmiko.ssh_exception import NetMikoTimeoutException
    from netmiko.ssh_exception import AuthenticationException
    from paramiko.ssh_exception import SSHException

    username = input("Enter username:  ")
    password = getpass()
    with open('commands_file.txt') as f:
        commands_list = f.read().splitlines()
    with open('devices_list.txt') as f:
        devices_list = f.read().splitlines()
    for devices in devices_list:
        print("Connecting to device:  " + devices)
        host_name_of_device = devices
        ios_device = {
            'device_type' : 'cisco_ios' ,
            'host' : host_name_of_device ,
            'username' : username ,
            'password' : password ,
        }
        try:
            net_connect = ConnectHandler(**ios_device)
        except (AuthenticationException):
            print("Authetication failure: " + host_name_of_device)
            continue
        except (NetMikoTimeoutException):
            print("Time out from device: " + host_name_of_device)
            continue
        except (EOFError):
            print("End of File reached: " + host_name_of_device)
            continue
        except (SSHException):
            print("Not able to SSH: Try with Telnet:  " + host_name_of_device)
            continue
        except Exception as unknown_error:
            print("other: " + unknown_error)
            continue
        output = net_connect.send_config_set(commands_list)
        print(output)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

netmiko can [autodetect](https://ktbyers.github.io/netmiko/docs/netmiko/ssh_autodetect.html) the type of the device. You should use this before running the commands.

```
from netmiko.ssh_autodetect import SSHDetect
...

    for devices in devices_list:
        print("Connecting to device:  " + devices)
        host_name_of_device = devices
        remote_device = {
            'device_type' : 'autodetect' , # Autodetect device type
            'host' : host_name_of_device ,
            'username' : username ,
            'password' : password ,
        }
        guesser = SSHDetect(**remote_device)
        best_match = guesser.autodetect()
        if best_match != 'cisco_ios':
            print("Device {} is of type {}. Ignoring "
                  "device".format(host_name_of_device, best_match))
            continue
        # Device type is cisco_ios
        remote_device['device_type'] = best_match # Detected device type
        try:
            net_connect = ConnectHandler(**remote_device)
```

Comment: That did work... I have tried your way which works when I have mixed kind of devices.. I even created script only for cisco which works fine now..

I am trying now for aruba OS Switches and that throws me error.

Comment: Thanks.. your format worked... 

How can I achieve same for Aruba Switches.. ?

Comment: This should be a separate question I believe, but I will try to point you in the right direction. netmiko doesn't have search patterns for aruba. But you can look at netmiko.ssh_autodetect.SSH_MAPPER_BASE dict in python interactive shell to see how existing patterns are defined, and add the pattern for aruba yourself before running autodetect. Something like netmiko.ssh_autodetect.SSH_MAPPER_BASE['aruba'] = {'cmd': 'a command', 'search_patterns': ['aruba something'], 'priority': 99, 'dispatch': '_autodetect_std'}

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.. I have asked that question here
https://stackoverflow.com/q/62419885/10172638
If you can check and review that..